# How do I represent many to many relation in the form of Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    ...

class Tag(db.Model):
    ...

class EntryTag(db.Model):
    entry = db.ReferenceProperty(Entry, required=True, collection_name='tag_set')
    tag = db.ReferenceProperty(Tag, required=True, collection_name='entry_set')
```

The template should be {{form.as_table}}

The question is how to make a form to create Entry where I can choose to add some of the tags ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a formset for your `EntryTag` class.  For more information, see [the Django formset docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#topics-forms-formsets).

Otherwise, you may wish to create a custom form with a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) and add the `EntryTag` entities using a custom view.